# Help with 2nd order ordinary differential equation and solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

I came across an ordinary differential equation of the form:

$y''+yy' + Ay + A = 0,$

Where $y=y(t)$, $A$ is some constant, positive or negative. So far the equation is solvable for $A=0$. Could somebody help in finding a general solution? The equation does not depend explicitly on $t$, and yet it is challenging to solve it.
I'm interested mostly in an analytical expression including special functions, series, etc., as long as there is such a solution. As a last resort, I'd go with polynomials or define special ones if needed.

Thank you

Comment: Most ODE do not have a symbolic solution of any kind. This means that changing a symbolically solvable ODE by changing coefficients or adding/removing terms will almost surely render it unsolvable in symbolic expressions. So if not even WolframAlpha can find a solution, then there does not exist one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y'(t)=p(y)$ and substitute in the ode,. Then $y''=p p'$ and ode becomes first order chini ode
$$
P'(y)=-y-A(1+y)P^{-1}
$$
Chini ode are not all solvable. I do not now have access to my PC to try solving this. But if the above can be solved for $P$, then you can now solve the original ode as first order ode using $y'=P$

Comment: The resulting Chini equation doesn't seem to be solvable explicitely or implicitely

Comment: If one multiplies the equation by $y'$, it is possible to reduce the equation if the integral $y(y')^2dt$ is known. If it is a constant, than the solutions are hypergeometric functions. What is the recipe for defining my own orthogonal polynomials that will give a solution?